# Can I write a stored procedure in Query Builder within SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to run the following procedure first:

```
exec ep_upd_server_abc
```

Then execute the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Server_Warehouse 
WHERE Enabled = 'f' and disabledweekly = 'f'
```

Can I write the following procedure in SSRS Query Builder so that I can execute two statements?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowDBJob
As
Begin
    exec ep_upd_server_abc;

    SELECT * FROM dbo.Server_Warehouse 
    WHERE Enabled = 'f' and disabledweekly = 'f'
End
```

Is there a work around for this?

I tried running this in SSRS Query Builder and it's giving me an error. Would appreciate any thoughts and suggestions...Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try running both statements (stored proc call and SELECT) in Query Builder?

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but... `declare @table TABLE (<results from proc>) Insert into @table exec ep_upd_erver_abc select * from @table union all select * from dbo.server_warehouse where enabled = 'F' and disabledweekly = 'f'`

Comment: What error did it give you?

Comment: wait... what does the stored procedure do?  update?  You cannot update from SSRS.

Comment: So I want the stored procedure to first run the following: ep_upd_server_abc -- this would excute an update in the backend and then run the following statement:                              SELECT * FROM dbo.Server_Warehouse 
    WHERE Enabled = 'f' and disabledweekly = 'f' to display a refreshed list...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do this exact procedure for

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowDBJob
As
Begin
    exec ep_upd_server_abc;

    SELECT * FROM dbo.Server_Warehouse 
    WHERE Enabled = 'f' and disabledweekly = 'f'
End
```

in SQL Management Studio and call that?  Don't do any type of real time event driven coding or procs in SSRS IMHO.  Slippery slope where you are trying to use the equivalent of a screwdriver for a hammer and vice versa.  SQL Managment studio is meant for designing proc's and accessing the SQL Server Database for it's object creation directly.  SSRS is meant to return data connections, results for a dataset, evaluating presentation of datasets on one or many objects to display and not much more except features/syntax around those things.  Even accessing temp tables '#(something)' and parameters declared on the fly 'declare @thing int (inside statement of dataset)' make it get mad.  Stick with predefined programable objects or procedures and functions already created.  Do not try to create them on the fly.

Plus think about this.  Everytime you are calling your dataset you cannot create that object each time as it already exists.  Then you are going to have to either alter it or drop it and recreate it first.  SSMS already does this part in options for you and stores them in the database.  SSRS is an add on to SQL Server but is not full featured for creating objects.  Especially on the fly.

Comment: @djangojazz..I did think about this and I've no permissions to write a stored procedure in the backend. I would think SSRS had the option and power to write stored procedures on the fly. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: No problem.  I have been in positions where I could not run procedure creations due to policy rules.  In those cases I would code up what you need and give it to a SQL Developer, DBA, admin that can.  SSRS does what it can do very well, beyond that it cannot do much.

Comment: Also, If you don't have enough permissions to create a object on SQL you won't be able to do it from any interface anyways. I agree with @djangojazz, This functionality is better of done on server by Admin.

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot write "Create Procedure" or any other DDL statements from Query Designer in RS. This is by design.